# BindingSource to ComboBox and [Browsable(false)] property to PropertyGrid don't work together

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, propertygrid

I will try to explain my issue.

I have got a class:

```
public class Person()
{
        [Browsable(false)]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        //...
}
```

I use `PropertyGrid` control to show `Name` field, but I don't need to show `Id`, so I set `Browsable` property to false like this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

In my GUI I present all elements of `Person` class in `ListView` control, and when an element is selected I show properties in `PropertyGrid` control like this:

```
void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   this.propertyGrid.SelectedObject = (object)this.listView.SelectedObject;
}
```

Everything works fine, `PropertyGrid` shows only field `Name`.

Then I need to use `ComboBox` control like this:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(...)
//.....

this.comboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(people, null);
this.comboBox.ValueMember = "Id"; // here an exeption has been thrown !!!
this.comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

And on line `this.comboBox.ValueMember = "Id";` got this error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll**

**Additional information: Cannot bind to the new display member.**

How to resolve this problem ?

PS: If I remove `[Browsable(false)]` line everything works fine, but `Id` field in `PropertyGrid` control will be shown

Comment: This appears to be a known issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442682/why-does-adding-a-browsablefalse-attribute-to-a-class-property-prevent-filte  ..and...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723207/custom-combobox-control-custom-datasource-with-custom-displaymember-and-valuemem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I duplicated the problem, and I solved it by setting the DataSource *after* setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(people, null);
```